# Google Mirror API

Tags: java, google-app-engine, opencv, google-glass

I have downloaded the Google Mirror Java Quick Start example from here:
https://github.com/googleglass/mirror-quickstart-java

And I have followed the instructions here:
https://developers.google.com/glass/develop/mirror/quickstart/java

I have successfully been able to upload the quick start example to one of my projects in Google App Engine. This has taken me a lot of time and effort to figure out. I am wondering if there is any way to use OpenCV in any of its forms (including JavaCV) with this quickstart example. In other words, is it possible to run OpenCV in any of its forms on Google App Engine?

My goal is to send an image to App Engine through the Mirror API and return an image processed by OpenCV as a result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think OpenCV is supported by App Engine, since it has dependencies on native libraries. There is an [issue](https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=7010&q=OpenCV&colspec=ID%20Type%20Component%20Status%20Stars%20Summary%20Language%20Priority%20Owner%20Log) raised and has not moved much. I would suggest that you host your OpenCV functionality on a server outside of AppEngine. Wrap the functionality and expose it as a Web Service. You could then invoke that from App Engine.

Comment: I am having trouble getting the project to run in Eclipse. I followed all of the instructions, downloaded it, imported it as a Maven project.  The instructions don't tell you how to get the mvn jetty to run in Eclipse.  I assumed it was automatic, but it Everything was fine until I try to start the project.

Answer (score 0):

I am not OpenCV guy but the Mirror API is not a convenient transport to send images from glass (I assume) to server. To send image to the server you will need to have users share image with some pseudo-contact which is counterintuitive (IMO) in this case. Simple HTTP client and file upload would do the work.

If authentication dance matters - then the pattern sample mirror app uses is good, but it can be applied for another API on server side, let's say Picasa.